# Saving FileSystemObject as UTF

Tags: asp-classic, utf-8, fso

how can i save the file in utf-8?

```
Dim FSO, File   
Set FSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")   
Set File = FSO.OpenTextFile(Path,2,true,-1)   
File.Write(xml1)   
File.Close   
Set File = Nothing  
Set FSO = Nothing
```

Comment: i'm using asp3 , any help 4 that?

Answer (score 5):

I'd try the ADODB Stream object.

```
Dim objStream 
Set objStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream.Type = adTypeText
objStream.Mode = adModeReadWrite
objStream.Open
objStream.Position = 0
objStream.Charset = "UTF-8"
objStream.WriteText strContent
objStream.SaveToFile strABSPath,adSaveCreateOverWrite
objStream.Close
Set objStream=nothing
```